# Random variable related to binomial

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The number of successes $A$ in $n$ independent trials with the probability of a success is $p$ for each trial is [binomially-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

I am interested in a scenario that adds dependence to the trials: suppose another successful trial cannot occur for $k-1$ trials after a successful trial, that is each success is followed by at least $k-1$ consecutive failures (if necessary for convenience, we can assume that the last $k-1$ trials in the sequence of $n$ are failures).  My questions are about the distribution of the number of successes $X$:

1. Provided that $k\leq n$, is there a "nice" expression for the probability mass function of the distribution of $X$?  I can calculate it for specific small $k$'s but don't see a pattern...
2. Is there a form of a Gaussian approximation for large $n$ with constants $k\ll n$ and $p$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp To obtain the p.m.f. I think the key is finding the expression for the number of ways one can "fit" $m$ non-overlapping sub-segments of length $k$ into a segment of length $n$. However, combinatorics isn't my strong suite and I can't figure that out. As for Gaussian approximation, for the binomial distribution it arises due to the Central Limit Theorem and the divisibility property of a binomial random variable (i.e. if $X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Binomial}(m,p)$, then $X+Y\sim\text{Binomial}(n+m,p)$). The sums here won't be as nice, but maybe they aren't too bad.

Comment: Posted a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040696/how-many-ways-can-one-fit-m-non-overlapping-sub-segments-of-length-k-into).

Answer (score 0):

We have a sample of $n$ Bernouli trials with a success probability of $p$ *except* for the $k-1$ trials subsequent to a success in which failure is certain.  Call these auto-fails.

Define a $k$ length success string, as one success followed by $k-1$ auto-fails which are automatic failures.

For there to be $X$ successes in the sample, there must be $X$ of $k$-length success strings and $n-kX$ failures in any order, OR a $1$-length to $(k-1)$-length success string preceded by any ordering of $X-1$ of $k$-length success strings and $n-1-k(X-1)$ to $n-k-k(X-1)$ failures.

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x) & ={n-x(k-1)\choose x, n-xk}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-kx} +\ddots
 \\ & \ddots + p^x \sum_{h=1}^{k-1} {n-h-(k-1)(x-1)\choose x-1, n-h-k(x-1)} (1-p)^{n-h-k(x-1)}
\end{align}$$

...

I can't see a way to simplify this at the moment.

Comment: By @victorsouza's solution to my [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040696/how-many-ways-can-one-fit-m-non-overlapping-sub-segments-of-length-k-into), shouldn't $\Pr(X=x)=\binom{n-x(k-1)}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-xk}$?