# How many ways can one "fit" $m$ non-overlapping sub-segments of length $k$ into a segment of length $n$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given discrete one-dimensional space (a "segment") of length $n$, how many ways can one fit a $m$ non-overlapping sub-segments of length $k$ in this space?

This seems like a very simple question, but my combinatorics skills don't seem sufficient to figure this out.  Any help?

This is related to my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040636/random-variable-related-to-binomial).

Comment: Don't have time to do more than wave my hands wildly, but possibly induction on n starting at n = m*k. Also, are the m sub-segments distinguishable or not?

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but isn't it just $C(n-m(k-1),k)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to count disjoint integer segments, it's convenient to look for non-negative integer solutions some diophantine equations. Consider the following:

$$ E_0 + L_1 + E_1 + L_2 + E_2 + \dotsc + L_m + E_m = n $$

Here, $E_j$ are the lengths of empty segments (that is, the segments that were not chosen) and $L_j$ are the lengths of segments that were chosen.
For instance, if $n = 10$, $m = 3$, than the solution:

$$ 2 + 3 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 0 = 10 $$

Refers to the choice of intervals $\{3,4,5\}$, $\{6,7\}$ and $\{9,10\}$.

For your specific problem, you want $L_j = k$ for all $j$, hence we have the equation:

$$ E_0 + k + E_1 + k + E_2 + \dotsc + k + E_m = n $$

$$ E_0 + E_1 + E_2 + \dotsc + E_m = n - mk $$

Each different solution of the latter equation is equivalent to a choice of non-overlapping segments of length $k$ on a segment of lenght $n$. But we know how to count solutions of such equations. We have $m+1$ variables totalizing $n-mk$, hence we have:

$$ \binom{(n-mk) + (m+1) - 1}{(m+1) - 1} = \binom{n - m(k-1)}{m}$$

solutions.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer!  One follow-up question: you say that "we know how to count solutions of [diophantine equation $E_0+E_1+\ldots+E_m=x$]".  Now this indeed looks like a very simple diophantine equation: a sum of $m+1$ non-negative variables and same constant (unity) multiplying each variable.  It looks like, in general, there are $\binom{x+t-1}{t-1}$ solutions for $\sum_{i=1}^ta_i=x$. But could you please point me to a source of this statement or explain how one derives it? There must be a textbook that contains this...

Comment: The simplest proof that I am aware uses the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) analogy and goes as follows:
Suppose you have $n$ stars and $t-1$ bars. A solution of such equation is equivalent to a permutation of these $n + t - 1$ objects. Indeed, a the bars are $t-1$ separators and the amount stars between bars are the value of $a_i$. There are $n + t - $ places that you can chose to put the $t-1$ separators, hence there are $\binom{n + t - 1}{ t-1 }$ ways to do so.